# CV for Lasso using specific lambda selected by cv.glmnet() function in R

Tags: r, lasso, glmnet

Based on a set of candidate lambda values, I'm using `cv.glmnet()` to select the best Lasso lambda.

Next, I want to use a different dataset to run 5-fold CV for Lasso using the `lambda.min` selected by `cv.glmnet()`, as lambda. The goal is to check the predictors selected by Lasso, in each fold.

However, I realized that, neither of `glmnet` or `cv.glmnet` accept single lambda values as input.

Do you know how I could proceed for the second part of my analysis?

Comment: That's strange....what happens if you supply the lambda sequence just repeating the same value?

Comment: What happens when you read `?glmnet`?

Answer (score 1):

You specify your lambda during the prediction and not training, using the parameter 's'. `predict(fit, data, s=mylambda)`